# Does Entity Framework Core support compound types?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm porting an older Entity Framework application to EF Core.  In the old application, there's liberal use of auditing information:

```
public class Audit
{
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDt { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedDt { get; set; }
}
```

This class is embedded in many Entitites in the DbContext, like so:

```
public class Order
{
    public decimal quantity { get; set; }
    public Guid SecurityId { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }
    public Audit Audit { get; set; }
}
```

Old EF has no problem with this use of embedded classes but Entity Framework Core doesn't like it.  It's forcing me to create an index for the embedded class Audit.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type 'Audit' requires a primary key to be defined.'
```

Any ideas on whether this is supported in the new EF and, if so, how to get around the requirement for a key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for "Owned Entity Types"

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities

```
public class StreetAddress
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public StreetAddress ShippingAddress { get; set; }
}

// OnModelCreating
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().OwnsOne(p => p.ShippingAddress);
```

---

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Classic](http://entityframework-classic.net/)

Another way to easily port your application is using EF Classic. It's a EF6 fork that also supports .NET Core